# Frozen Columns with PrimeNG - Misalignment

Tags: angular, primeng

Good day,

I have followed the example code from [primeng-frozen-column-example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-table-frozen-columns-dpsm8l?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-scroll-demo.component.ts). The code below does not seem to have an effect on the table at all.

```
makeRowsSameHeight() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if ($('.ui-table-scrollable-wrapper').length) {
           let wrapper = $('.ui-table-scrollable-wrapper');
           wrapper.each(function () {
           let w = $(this);
           let frozen_rows: any = w.find('.ui-table-frozen-view tr');
           let unfrozen_rows = w.find('.ui-table-unfrozen-view tr');
           for (let i = 0; i < frozen_rows.length; i++) {
                if (frozen_rows.eq(i).height() > 
                    unfrozen_rows.eq(i).height()) {
                    unfrozen_rows.eq(i).height(frozen_rows.eq(i).height());
                } else if (frozen_rows.eq(i).height() < 
                    unfrozen_rows.eq(i).height()) {
                    frozen_rows.eq(i).height(unfrozen_rows.eq(i).height());
                }
           }
        });
       }
    });
  }
```

The frozen columns rows are misaligned as per the image -> [Frozen Column misalignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJBJG.png).

The alignment of the rows is misaligned how can this issue be fixed?

Comment: can you share your html code which is responsible for table rendering and the full component code?

Comment: Yes, The files just have many lines of code. The component file has about 1000 lines code and the Html 430 lines of code.  What would be the best way to provide you with the code associated?